# ¿Como puedo crear variables dinámicas dentro de un loop?

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando un pagina para saber el precio de criptomonedas en tiempo real y estoy tratando de hacer todo de una manera dinamica.

Al cargar mi archivo JS hace una consulta a la base de datos para obtener un array de las cripto que busco me regresa lo siguiente:

CryptosEnableISOCode = ["BTC","ETH","XRP","LTC","BCH","DOGE"]

Hasta aquí todo bien la cosa es que cuando quiero obtener el precio de estas hago lo siguiente

```
let DBRefCurrentPricesCrypto = firebase.database().ref('System/CurrentPrices/' + CurrencySelected)

DBRefCurrentPricesCrypto.on('value', (SSCurrentPricesCrypto) => {

    if (SSCurrentPricesCrypto.val() != null) {

        let SSCPCV = SSCurrentPricesCrypto.val()

        CryptosEnableCurrentPrices = []
        CryptosEnableCurrentPrices.push(SSCPCV.BTCPrice)
        CryptosEnableCurrentPrices.push(SSCPCV.ETHPrice)
        CryptosEnableCurrentPrices.push(SSCPCV.XRPPrice)
        CryptosEnableCurrentPrices.push(SSCPCV.LTCPrice)
        CryptosEnableCurrentPrices.push(SSCPCV.BCHPrice)
        CryptosEnableCurrentPrices.push(SSCPCV.DOGEPrice)
        initSetDOMCurrentPrice()

    }

})
```

Como pueden ver el codigo anterior no me permite cargar los precios de manera dinámica y en caso de que quiera agregar otra crypto a la base de dato se obviara las crypto nuevas
asi que estoy tratando de hacer algo asi

```
let DBRefCurrentPricesCrypto = firebase.database().ref('System/CurrentPrices/' + CurrencySelected)

DBRefCurrentPricesCrypto.on('value', (SSCurrentPricesCrypto) => {

    if (SSCurrentPricesCrypto.val() != null) {

        let SSCPCV = SSCurrentPricesCrypto.val()

        for(let i = 0; i < CryptosEnableISOCode.length; i++){

            CryptoToGet = CryptosEnableISOCode[i] // Esto seria por ejemplo BTC luego ETH, XRP y asi


            CryptosEnableCurrentPrices.push(SSCPCV.CryptoToGet + "Price")   //Aqui obtendria el valor guardado en BTCPrice 
            // o crear una variable
             var CryptoToGet + "Price" = SSCPSV.CrypoToGet +"Price" 

        }

        initSetDOMCurrentPrice()

    }     

})
```

Hasta donde yo se esto no es posible, pero igual no lo se todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el método `Object.keys()` para obtener los tipos de tu objeto `SSCPCV` y recorrerlas en un ciclo para decidir cuales agregar a tu objeto `CryptosEnableCurrentPrices`

```js
CryptosEnableCurrentPrices = [];
 
var SSCPCV = {}; // Este es tu objeto SSCPCV 
SSCPCV.BTCPrice = 1.0 ;
SSCPCV.ETHPrice = 2.0 ;
SSCPCV.XRPPrice = 3.0 ;
SSCPCV.LTCPrice = 4.0 ;
SSCPCV.BCHPrice = 5.0 ;
SSCPCV.DOGEPrice = 6.0 ;

var misKeys = Object.keys(SSCPCV);
//console.log(misKeys)

misKeys.forEach( function(valor, indice, array) {
        if (valor.toUpperCase().includes("PRICE"))
      CryptosEnableCurrentPrices.push( SSCPCV[valor])
} );

console.log(CryptosEnableCurrentPrices)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona solo una cosa mas ¿Hay alguna manera de modificar el orden en el que se guardan para que sean exactamente BTC(Index: 0), ETH(Index:1) etc?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo siempre y cuando devuelvas el número de indice que le corresponde a cada elemento , devolviendo el objeto `SSCPCV` en orden, o estableciendo un orden predeterminado. Pero eso ya depende de tu caso de uso y si solo consumes información o tienes la libertad de elegir lo que se devuelve